# Selenium multiple instance running the same script

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on this automation program on python that lets me enter text and then submit it onto a website. However the number of text that I have is very large and I can enter only 1 line of text at a time and then have to reload the page, I have to login to the website first so driver.get() isn't that much useful as the website doesn't store my credentials. So I have to manually login and do that things first which I have done, but now I want to run multiple instance of this script at the same time. I believe that running the same script in different tab of a same browser instance isn't possible. I read about selenium grid and understood a little about how it works but I haven't been able to implement it. Is there any way I can ease up my process?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:9222")

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, chrome_options=chrome_options)


def subject():
  content = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.btn-default')
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", content)
  try:
     content = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[text()="Okay"]')
     driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", content[1])
  except IndexError:
     driver.refresh()

while True:
with open('name_list.txt','r') as f:
  for line in f:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    search = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'class_name')))
    search.send_keys(line)
    subject()
    content = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Submit"]')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", content)
    driver.refresh()
```

I hope I find some help. I tried using pytest but I don't know how to implement it when I am running on a host and want to do the upload task from that same port.

Comment: You need to use xml file to run with multiple instances

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="instances" thread-count="2">
    <test name="Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="Parallel"/>
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-

This is XML file
```

Comment: Would be so kind as to direct me on how to attach this? I have the due date on 3 days and I have not been able to do it. Are there any documentation on this?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Y6knVutUsI  Please follow this tutorial and https://www.guru99.com/sessions-parallel-run-and-dependency-in-selenium.html

Comment: Thank you for the help, but my program is written in python :)

Comment: The idea is the same buy only programing language is the only change 
If my answer useful to you accept/tick my answer